# how to append a number to end of a string in angular?

Tags: angular

I am looping through a list of products in Angular, I would like to append the index to the opened or closed value, can anyone help here please?

```
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let product of products;
                                let i = index;
                                let last = last;
                                let first = first;
                                let even = even;
                                let odd = odd;" (opened)="panelOpenState = true"
                                                 (closed)="panelOpenState = false">
                                <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                                    <mat-panel-title>
                                        {{product.name}} {{i}}
                                    </mat-panel-title>
                                    <mat-panel-description>
                                        Currently I am {{panelOpenState ? 'open' : 'closed'}}
```

So I would like to do something like the following:

```
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let product of products;
                                let i = index;
                                let last = last;
                                let first = first;
                                let even = even;
                                let odd = odd;" (opened)="panelOpenState{{i}} = true"
                                                 (closed)="panelOpenState{{i}} = false">
                                <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                                    <mat-panel-title>
                                        {{product.name}} {{i}}
                                    </mat-panel-title>
                                    <mat-panel-description>
                                        Currently I am {{panelOpenState{{i}} ? 'open' : 'closed'}}
```

but this doesn't work?!  Expected identifier, keyword or string

Comment: is panelOpenState an array?

Answer (score 1):

> Just change it like this.

```
 Currently I am {{panelOpenState ? `open ${i}` : `closed ${i}`}}
```

This `open ${i}` and `closed ${i}`are called template literals.